# Use Google Maps API satalite imagery as base layer for OpenLayers 3

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, single-page-application, openlayers-3

Really I'm just trying to find out if I should continue to try to make this work...it doesn't seem like it's supported in any meaningful way.

I have an SPA site run on AngularJS that I have added an OpenLayers 3 map to.

Currently we are using our own imagery but we want to move to using Google Maps API as the base satellite imagery layer.

1. It doesn't appear that OpenLayers 3 supports Google Maps API...is this true?  meaning is there no supported way to use Google Maps API along with OpenLayers 3
2. The Google Maps API examples all use a pretty archaic way of adding a map to a page that is NOT Angular friendly...why is this, am I missing something?
3. I've found at least one javascript library OLGM.js that tries to bridge the gap to allow for use of google maps api with OpenLayers 3 but this is also NOT angularJS friendly.  I can't figure out how to get things loaded in the correct order and also have access to olgm.js globally (via a js bundler)  so that I can actually use it.

Any insight or examples that anyone can point me to would be greatly appreciated.

If we solve this here I will definitely post the entire solution to joining all these technologies.

Comment: I was using Google Maps satellite on their previous version. But since the last version, it seems that Google doesn't allow their imagery to be used outside of GMaps anymore. I was looking for a solution months ago but did not find anything. So now I use Bing imagery instead.